# Regex, select only time

Tags: regex

I need to remove the first two lines of numbers and keep only the text. How can I select that with regex? Here is a short example of a much longer text:

```
112
00:04:04,349 --> 00:04:09,000
should give over to the community which

113
00:04:06,989 --> 00:04:11,159
which I'm also a little bit more

114
00:04:09,000 --> 00:04:13,169
skeptical camp I think that there's at
```

I tried many things but I am learning Regex and I am quite lost. For instance:

```
[\d:>\s-]*\n
```

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/VQrhlo/1 with `PCRE`.

Comment: @Zenoo: you are right. I tried many things before asking but I am learning and I could not solve it.

Comment: If this is a file-based task, consider using a line-oriented processing tool like sed. Then you needn't find a regex spanning lines, you might even opt for a regex to detect text if that's easier in your setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logic**:

If the string ONLY has multiple occurrences of `\d` or `:` or `>` or `\s` between the start and end of line, match and replace them with blank strings

Replace each match with an empty string using this regex:

```
^[\d:,> -]+$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkIvmD/5/)**

OR you can use,

```
^[^a-zA-Z]+$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkIvmD/4/)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `[\d:,> -]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit or a `:` or `>` or `:` or a space
- `$` - asserts the end of the line

Comment: `^[\d:,->\s]+(?:\n|$)` can remove lines

Comment: @Aaron See [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/UkIvmD/5/)

Comment: Also `^[^a-zA-Z]+$` would fail to remove non text lines which happen to have a character.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Gurman The question ask to remove lines as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try removing the two number lines via a regex replace:

```
^\d+$
^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}.*$
```

Then replace the above two patterns with empty string.  I don't see how pure regex will get you anywhere with regard to actually updating your file.

Comment: Your regex works well in this example. The problem is that it is just a sample of a much longer text. \d are nor always 2 or 3 could be anything

Comment: @Nrc The `{2}` and `{3}` terms are _quantities_, not literal numbers.  They mean match any two or three digits.

Comment: That is what I mean, they are not allways 2 or 3 digits

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match only digits in the first line and match the next line, you could try:

[`^\d+\r?\n.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/s7Tu77/1)

**Explanation**

- match one or more digites `\d+`
- match an optional carriage return and a newline `\r?\n`
- match any character zero or more times `.*`
- the end of the string `$`

Then you could use replace to replace with an empty string.

Comment: If a line contains only a single digit say 1 to 9, then 1st regex - [`^\d.*\d$`](https://regex101.com/r/QsoyM0/4/) would not match because it tries to find at digit at the beggining and at the end of a line

Comment: @Gurman That is a fair point, I've updated my answer and removed that part.